# how to display json data fetched using ajax in each tab

Tags: ajax, json, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a struts 2 action class with a method which returns json data.

I have 8 tabs on my jsp. When a user clicks on a tab, I'd like to make an ajax call to this method. I would like the returned json data to be parsed and decorated with html that can be rendered in this tab.

I'm using jquery tabs to make [tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#ajax).

- How can I capture the returned json data ? Can I subscribe to some event that jquery publishes ?
- How can I process the returned json data ? For e.g.; json data:

{ City : {name="New York", alias="NY", imgPath="filePath/img1.jgp"} }

I would like to extract the name and bold it.
Use the imgPath to define img tag, etc

Comment: first you need to make dynamically ul > li structure using json data . and then empty the old div add new ul > li and call bind again for tabs.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            var data = { "City": [{ "name": "New York1", "alias": "NY1", "imgPath": "filePath/img1.jgp" }, { "name": "New York2", "alias": "NY2", "imgPath": "filePath/img2.jgp" }, { "name": "New York3", "alias": "NY3", "imgPath": "filePath/img3.jgp" }, { "name": "New York4", "alias": "NY4", "imgPath": "filePath/img4.jgp"}] };

            if (data.City.length > 0) {
                $('body').prepend('<div id="tabs1"><ul></ul></div>');

                $.each(data.City, function (i, entity) {
                    $('#tabs1 ul').append($('<li><a href="#tabs1-' + (i + 1) + '">' + entity.name + '</a></li>'));
                    $('#tabs1').append('<div id="tabs1-' + (i + 1) + '"><p>Image Path:' + entity.imgPath + '</p></div>');
                });

                $("#tabs1").tabs();
            }
        });​
```

for live demo see this link: http://jsfiddle.net/nanoquantumtech/ffbx5/

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the returned Json data by passing the data argument to the ajax calls success callback method which will be executed on success.  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

You can use `jQuery parse.json` method and pass the json string to it. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

One more thing that your example json string is not looks like valid one. You can check your json is valid or not from this link http://jsonlint.com/ by simply pasting your json data or by pasting the url.